# Error occur during running the tesseract OCR engine in my application

Tags: java, android, tesseract

Can I know what is the error when I debug my application? Below is my coding and the tessdata is saved inside my phone.

```
public class testingtesting extends Activity {

private static final String data_path = "/mnt/sdcard/tessdata";

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //    setContentView(R.layout.image);

        ImageView a = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.testingtesingt);
        Bitmap aa =  grayScale.bitmap_in_binarize;
  //      a.setImageBitmap(aa);

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        System.out.println("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");
        //error

      //  File myDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        baseApi.init(data_path, "eng");
        //error
        baseApi.setImage(aa);
        System.out.println("adwdwawdada");
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();
        System.out.println("cimcaoioievfoaemmov");
        Intent intent = new Intent(testingtesting.this, result.class);
        intent.putExtra("title_input", recognizedText);
        startActivity(intent);


 }
```

Comment: Which files do you have in /mnt/sdcard/tessdata? And please include the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the error message.

From what I can gather, you're having trouble with `System.out.println("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");`

Android does not use standard Java console. Instead, use Logcat like this:

```
Log.d("testingtesting", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");
```

If you're using Eclipse, open LogCat view to see your app's output when you launch it:

Window → Show View → Other → Android → LogCat

More information on LogCat [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: want to ask why i get this in my logcat when i run the project?

finalize(): NOT calling nativeFinalize() due to premature garbage collection

finalize(): calling super.finalize()

Comment: Seems to me an entirely different error. LogCat should give you a stack trace. One of the top methods is the one that caused it.